# Realizing you're unknowingly carry an item on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

What is the best thing to do when you realize that you're unknowingly carrying an item on Shabbos? Is the following correct:

When the person was carrying unknowingly, he was misasek (making a work of Shabbat when he was thinking he doesn't), so he wasn't doing a milacha, which requires mileches machsheves (intentional work) If he continues walking after he realizes he's carrying, he now is doing a mileches machsheves by walking 4 amos (4 cubits). Therefore he should stop and put down what he was carrying. The original akirah (moving an object from its previous place) was done without the knowledge, so it should count as nothing.

Comment: See Eruvin Perek Hamotse tefilin